# Add product to cart from functions.php

Tags: functions

What I'm trying to accomplish is when the checkout page is accessed with certain get arguments a product to be added to the cart.

```
function my_custom_function() {
  if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'checkout/?some=argv' ) {
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 90759, 1 );
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_function', 7 );
```

I tried this but when I access the checkout page it's not added to the cart and i get redirected to the cart page.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out

```
function my_custom_function() {
    global $woocommerce;
  if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/checkout/?a=b' ) {
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( 90759, 1 );
    // exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_function', 7 );
```